# How to Get Monitor Info with Autohotkey?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8, desktop-application, autohotkey

I try to get current monitor status and found GetMonitorInfo function at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144901(v=vs.85).aspx but I do not know [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and how to use it in [autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey). DllCall line is just a guess so this is what I wrote for now.

```
MonitorStatus := 1 > 2  ; Creates a boolean variable so size of it is determined.
Sleep 1000
DllCall("GetMonitorInfo","HMONITOR",1,"LPMONITORINFO",MonitorStatus,"int")
Sleep 1000
MsgBox Monitor status is %MonitorStatus%.   ; Status should be turned to 1.
Return
```

Shortly how to detect if monitor is on or off with assuming it has power?

Answer (score 0):

The DllCall returns a pointer to the structure. I think it's somehow possible to use pointers in Autohotkey but i don't think is going to be easy. If you don't know what any of that means don't even bother.

Hmm.. looks like autohotkeys does have everything; Try this:

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SysGet.htm

And don't forget to check the examples at the bottom of the page!

Comment: I saw it before but it does not contain sub-command which I search for.

Comment: what are you seraching for?

Comment: I want to know if monitor is on or off. Also added this sentence to question for clarifying it now.

Comment: If the monitor is not powered?
That will be very hard to do with autohotkey only.

Comment: Assume monitor has power always in other words I want to know if Windows is sending blank signal or a video signal to monitor.

Comment: Try what happens if you use PixelGetColor when monitor is suppose to be blank. I think it should return 0x000000 (black) for every pixel on the screen.

Comment: Tried it but turning screen off does not effect pixel and it gets actual color not black.

Comment: Therefore Windows always sends video signal but there is a second signal which tells to monitor if it should work or not.